# How to call non-static method from static method of the viewController class in swift?

Tags: swift

Hello I would like to know how to call a non static method from static method in the `UIViewController` class.

what i did is:

```
 public static func cambiarPosicion(posicion: Int){

    var reserva :   ReservaViewController = ReservaViewController()

    reserva.cambiarContainer(posicion: posicion)

}
```

But for calling the method that I want in the `UIViewController` I have created a instance of the same viewController(ReservaViewController) as you see. Then I used it for call a method called `cambiarContainer`  but I have a problem in that method, the error is :

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

and some code that I have in that method and where I have the error is:

```
self.btnSelectUbicacion.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: 
    "fondo_transparente"), for: .normal)
self.btnSelectServicio.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .normal)
self.btnSelectHora.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: 
  "fondo_transparente"), for: .normal)
self.btnConfirmacionReserva.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: 
  "fondo_transparente"), for: .normal)
```

The error is in the first line
I think that this problem is because I am calling the method from another instance, it is for that reason that I would like to know how to call a non method static from a static method.

Comment: It looks like this is some static function that you’ve defined so that some external object can trigger the some position update in an instance of this view controller, but doesn’t have that reference. Obviously, this approach is wrong, but before we can advise, we need to know what is calling this static method and its relation to the view controller, if any. Answer is going to be to retire this static method and replace with some delegate protocol, closure properties, or custom notification. But we can’t say which without more info.

Answer (score 1):

Because a static field/method--by definition--is not tied to any single object/instance of the class, while a non-static field/method always refers to an actual object/instance in some way.

So, you can't call non static method inside static method.

Comment: The only way it could be done would be for the static function to take an instance of its class as a parameter and then use the method on that instance of the class within the static function.  It'd work, *but I can't think of any scenario where this would be a good idea!*

Answer (score 0):

Think of a class as a factory. Say we have a Car class. The class is the factory that makes the cars. An instance of a Car is an actual car, in a specific color, with a license tag, that belongs to somebody.

You can tell an instance of car to set its radio to a given station. It doesn't make sense to do that from the factory however. ("Hey car factory, set the radio on Bob's car to 'Hits 101'").

Answer (score 0):

If you use storyboard or.xib file with UIViewController, you should create the controller with create its storyboard or .xib:

with .xib file:

```
ViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil)
```

with .storyBoard:

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "storyboardName", bundle: nil)
 let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerIdentifier")
```